# Ecto query for self-referencing association

Tags: join, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I've implemented a `User` self-referencing association as a way for a `user` to follow another `user`...the typical followers/following model. I am confused on how to implement a correct query expression for each function below. I understand what suppose to be done for each function but I don't know how to implement them.

```
defmodule App.User do  

  schema "users" do
    #...
    has_many :followers, App.Follower, foreign_key: :followed_id
    has_many :following, through: [:followers, :follower]
  end

  #...  

  @doc """
  Return true if `user` is following `user2`
  """
  def following?(user, user2) do
  end

  @doc """
  Return true if `user` is followed by `user2`
  """
  def followed_by?(user, user2) do
  end

  @doc """
  `user` follows `user2` 
  """
  def follow(user, user2) do
  end

  @doc """
  `user` unfollows `user2` 
  """
  def unfollow(user, user2) do
  end

end
```

The `Follower` schema:

```
schema "followers" do
  belongs_to :followed, User
  belongs_to :follower, User

  timestamps()
end
```

Comment: `following?` and `followed_by?` Could just do a lookup in the join table to see if the record is there, could it not?
`follow` could do a Repo.insert into the join table with both id's and `unfollow` remove such a record. They should be one-liners each.

Comment: Thanks Johannes. I understand what suppose to be done for each function but I don't know how to implement them. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Elixir as well but I'll probably need this in the future so I had a look into this. I would try;

```
def following?(user, user2) do
  user = Repo.get(User, user) |> Repo.preload(:followers)
  followers = hd(user.followers)
  Enum.any?(followers, fn e -> e == user2 end)
end
```

I'm not sure if this helps but I would go for something like this. I cannot test it at the moment either. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Upon first glance, your Schemas look good to me. I'd try something like this:

```
def follow(user, user2) do
  Repo.insert! %Follower{follower: user2, followed: user}
end

def following?(user, user2) do
  !! Repo.get_by(Follower, [follower: user2, followed: user]) # !! so that it returns true or false. You can also write xy != nil.
end
```

Check out [Ecto.Repo](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html) and you will be able to do the other two methods easily. :-)

Comment: FYI: I'm not sure whether you have to use id's at some point or using the user structs should be okay.